# Rails paginator error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently using rails 2.3.8.. I have got this error message when paginating my views?

> undefined method `foos_url' for #ActionView::Base:0xf4e92cc
>   Extracted source (around line #52):
>   50:       <%= @page.number %>
>   51:       <%= link_to("Prev", foos_url(:page => @page.prev.number)) if @page.prev? %>
>   52:       <%= link_to("Next", foos_url(:page => @page.next.number)) if @page.next? %>

I have done with  the instruction given in http://paginator.rubyforge.org/
How can i get out of this?

Answer (score 1):

In terminal, within the project's folder type in `rake routes | grep foos` and see if there's any match. Is there's no -- check the Chris Barretto's answer.

Also note that `paginator` gem seem to be out of date. Consider using `will_paginate` or `kaminary` gem (although, later seems to only support Rails 3.x).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have

routes.rb

```
map.resources :foos
```

foos_controller.rb

```
def index
end
```